# For skobbler maps iOS sdk Is it possible to delay or disable asking for location permissions?

Tags: ios, skmaps

By default it seems whenever the skobbler map is loaded, the user is prompted for their location permissions. For our app we have a current location button and we'd like to not ask for the location permissions of the user until they press the current location button for the first time.

Is there any way to do this with skobbler? Thanks.

One thing I tried that didn't end up working was setting skobblerMapView.settings.showCurrentPosition to NO but it still asked for the permissions.

Comment: It's not possible at this moment. Will be included in the next update

Comment: Was this included in the latest update? If so can you point me to the documentation for it? thanks.

Comment: The update will be available these months (Jan-Feb 2016)

Comment: Update available in the 3.0 build: http://forum.skobbler.com/showthread.php/7650-iOS-3-0-beta-build-update-28-06-2016